# Selenium - double click on item in picklist

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate some of the form filling in my web applications. I have section of the form that is a multi-select list, where the user double clicks the options they want from a box on the left (Available), and they get moved to the box on the right box (Chosen) when they are double clicked. It looks like this:

[image]

When I inspect the elements, the box on the left looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure how to replicate this functionality in Selenium using Python. I'm trying to get the list as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("fframeworkpage:j_id28:sections_1:j_idd0:sections_23:j_idd164:sections_25:j_idd172:field4_unselected")
```

But I'm not sure how to select an option within the list, and how to double on said option.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

[image]

[image]

UPDATE 2:

```
action = ActionChains(driver)    
parent = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@title='Attendance Options']")
element = parent.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='1']")
action.double_click(element).perform()

parent2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@title='Services Offered']")
element2 = parent2.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='1']")
action.double_click(element2).perform()
```

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the **value** parameter of the list element you'd like to click, you could directly select it using the XPATH selector of the element, as follows with `value='1'` as an example:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='1']")
```

If you then wanted to click the element to add it to the **Chosen** list, you'd call the `click()` method:

```
element.click()
```

If you instead wanted to refine your search and select the list of elements first, you can once again use the XPATH of the list knowing that the label of the HTML DOM element:

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//optgroup[@label='Available']")
```

Then you can select an element of the list using a method of your choice.

To double click an element you'd need to use an ActionChain:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
...
element = ...
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.double_click(element).perform()
```

Considering that you have two boxes with `label='Available'` you'd need to refine your search even more, by going up a layer in your HTML to select the parent. You can first select the `<select ...` element knowing that the **title** is *Services Offered - Available* once again using an XPATH selector:

```
parent = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@title='Services Offered - Available']")
```

Considering that `parent` is a WebElement, you can call any of the WebElement *find* methods to refine your selection and select a child - such as parent.find_element_by_id(...) for example, or parent.find_element_by_xpath(...).

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work for a single click, but not for a double click. If I use the list to select all the items in Available, how do I select an option within that list? I have another similar selection box with other values which also have values 1 onwards, how will it know which box to select from?

Comment: I've added an example of a double click :) You can call any of the methods for selection on the list, as it is a WebElement - such as list.find_element_by_id(...) for example, or list.find_element_by_xpath(...). I'd need more context to be able to say how it will know which box to select.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of both the boxes for selection and the inspection of the second box in the main pose. When I try to run the code it can't seem to differentiate since "//option[@value='1']" exists on both the left boxes. Any way to make it work for both?

Comment: See the end of the answer above, added a bit.

Comment: I added the code that I'm trying to the main post. However, it only selects the first item (from Attendance Option) and stops, and does not add anything from Services Offered.

Comment: driver.implicitly_wait(20) is a config option and does not actually wait. You'll need to investigate using WebDriverWait() to wait for the presence of an element before working with it. You've also used a variation of the actualt title in your selector. Use console logging to debug any further issues.

Comment: Even when I try to use: parent = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@title='Services Offered - Available']"), it still seems to only double click the item in the Attendance Items box.

Comment: You probably need to wait for the next element to become available. Check the console logs to see what's happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171116/discussion-between-yodascholtz-and-flamedra).